# How to zoom in or enlarge pictures in pycharm pro jupyter notebook preview?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, ipython

[image]

I am using Pycharm Pro's jupyter notebook feature.

I am displaying images, and they show up in the "Preview" pane.

I want to look closer at images, enlarge them, save them and so on.

Right click doesn't do anything.

What's the secret?

Comment: I think you can only slide the preview and make it bigger.

Comment: My conclusion in the year since then was never to use Jupyter notebook, as it is bad as an IDE. It only serves as a better power-point for presentations with code.